# отображение одинаковых элементов в консоли хрома

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

как сделать так чтоб в консоли одинаковые элементы отображались,а не просто показывалось сколько их ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В хроме в консоли нажать три точки в правом верхнем углу, Settings, поставить галочку "Show timestamps".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получится так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]